# "Available to help" vs. "available for help"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, nouns, prepositions

Which phrase is correct, "available to help" or "available for help"? I have mostly seen "available for help" but am confused which phrase to use.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct according to their own context.

'to' can be infinitive that is not followed by noun or gerund, but verb. For example:
1. I am available to help him.

'for' is used when it is followed by noun or gerund.
Thus, you can also say:
1. I am available for help (=noun).
2. I am available for helping (=gerund) him.

Comment: Thank you Iqbal. My understanding is, if I use "to" it should be related to someone or time related e.g. available to help you, available to help 24-7 etc. "For" doesn't need any further explanation e.g. We are available for help. What's your opinion?

Comment: @ALI You can simply say: "when we use "to", it can be followed by verb, e.g. I am available to help (=verb) you. While, when we use "for", it's followed by gerund or noun, e.g. I am available for help (=noun) or I am available for helping (=gerund) him/her/them".